# How to convert a string with different 0 values, in a single value ranging from 1 to 4 (n° of values different from zero)

Tags: python, r, pandas, converters

I Have the following table:

[image]

and for each cell, I'd like to obtain the n° of values different from 0.

As an example for the first 2 rows:

```
denovoLocus10   9   C   0   1   0

denovoLocus12   7   G   3   3   4
```

Comment: I am not sure if you want `R` or `Python` solution as you have tagged both of the languages?

Comment: It seems that you have a pandas image. You need to include a text format of the data. eg you could run `df.to_dict()` and paste the result here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a simple test data frame, as the data itself is in a screenshot rather than something copyable:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['0/0/0/0', '0/245/42/0']})
```

Just extract all integers as strings using a regular expression, replace all strings `'0'` with `np.nan`. Then count, within each original-index-level group (note that `count` excludes `NaN` automatically):

```
>>> df['A_count'] = df['A'].str.extractall(r'(\d+)').replace('0', np.nan) \
...     .groupby(level=0).count()
>>> df
            A  A_count
0     0/0/0/0        0
1  0/245/42/0        2
```

If you want it to do it with multiple columns, filter your columns and loop over them with a for loop. (This also could be done with an `apply` over those columns.) Eg:

```py
for c in df.filter(regex=r'RA\d{2}_R1_2'):
    df[c + '_count'] = df[c].str.extractall(r'(\d+)').replace('0', np.nan) \
        .groupby(level=0).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it in `R`.

```r
#load package
library(tidyverse)

#here is the data you gave us
test_data <- tibble(Tag = paste0("denovoLocus", c(10, 12, 14, 16, 17)),
       Locus = c(9,7,37,5,4),
       ref = c("C", "G", "C", "T", "C"),
       RA02_R1_2 = c("0/0/0/0", "22/0/262/1", "0/0/0/0", "0/0/0/0", "0/7/0/0"),
       RA03_R1_2 = c("0/223/0/0", "22/0/989/15", "0/5/0/0", "0/0/0/0", "0/42/0/0"),
       RA06_R1_2 = c("0/0/0/0", "25/3/791/3", "0/4/0/0", "0/0/0/8", "0/31/0/3"))

#split and count the elements that do not equal zero and them collapse them
test_data%>%
  mutate(across(RA02_R1_2:RA06_R1_2, ~map_dbl(., ~str_split(.x, pattern = "/") %>%
                                            map_dbl(., ~sum(.x != "0") )))) %>%
  unite(col = "final", everything(), sep = " ")
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   final                   
#>   <chr>                   
#> 1 denovoLocus10 9 C 0 1 0 
#> 2 denovoLocus12 7 G 3 3 4 
#> 3 denovoLocus14 37 C 0 1 1
#> 4 denovoLocus16 5 T 0 0 1 
#> 5 denovoLocus17 4 C 1 1 2
```

First using `across` I summarize the columns with a bunch of "/". I first split the elements by "/" using `str_split`, then I count the elements that do not equal zero (`sum(.x != "0")`). It is a little complicated because splitting produces a list, so you need to `map` over the list to pull the values out. Lastly, we use `unite` to collapse all the columns into the string format that you wanted.